# Node/Express mutliple proxy servers every curl/sdk

Tags: node.js

I am on linux and looking to use multiple proxy servers for each
of my api calls. for example aws sdk, I have 3 accounts. I will use 3
different proxy servers on 1 call. and if I use curl will use different 
proxy servers for each call. basically in a loop. will this be possible?

app.js will use 3 different api. or let say 3 different api keys of the same sdk. so when api-1 will be iterated. it will use proxy-1 or what ever was designated to it. api-2 proxy-2, etc.

Comment: Can you please provide details of what you've tried and also clarify what you mean by 3 different proxy servers on 1 call? Does this mean to rotate through the proxies?

Comment: Updated the descriptions. so when I run my app.js it will iterate to 3 api keys from and sdk. each key/iteration will use a different proxy.